# What is the security gain of applying Two S-boxes in Different Ways?

Tags: s-boxes, feistel-network

In a 128-bits Feistel Cipher:

I need suggestions about two variations of the Round Function

**Variation-1**

1. $64$ bit input is divided into $8$ bytes
2. Byte $0,1,2,3$ are substituted with Sbox1
3. Byte $4,5,6,7$ are substituted with Sbox2.
4. Then a $8 \times 8$ Binary Matrix is applied on the 8 bytes from 8 rows (Matrix similar to Camellia).

[image: Variation-1]

**Variation-2**

1. 64 bit input of the round function is expressed as $8 \times 8$ binary matrix.
2. Sbox1 is applied on the rows (on 8 bytes).
3. Sbox2 is applied on the columns (on 8 bytes).
4. 8 Bytes are made using bits of Rows.
5. Then a $8 \times 8$ Binary Matrix is applied on the 8 bytes from 8 rows (Matrix similar to Camellia).

[image: Variation - 2]

Keeping in view that both S-boxes have non-linearity of 112 and maximum Differential Probability of $2^{-6}$ ($\approx$ the same level of security of AES).

**Which variation is better in terms of security ?** The same S-boxes are used in both the variations. Variation-2 is slow and more complex to implement, but thats not a issue

Comment: And exactly what is the question ? O.o

Comment: i mean which variation is better in terms of security. bcz same sboxes are used in both the variations. Variation-2 is slow and more complex to impliment, but thats not a issue

Comment: You ever hear of a P-box?

Comment: it is used in camellia. 8x8 Binary Matrix.

Comment: no, that is the P-function, see the P-box in DES

Comment: what does Pbox has to do with both variations? The Only thing different in both variations is how the Sboxes are being used.

Comment: S-box provide confusion while the P-box provide a diffusion. I'm not sure your 8x8 matrix provide the sufficiant diffusion intended.

Comment: i am saying both variations wil have same P-box, so no need to compare the P-box, the question is about usage of Sboxes. in Two Variations nothing is changed except how the Sboxes are being used. I hope you understood @Biv

Comment: You should specify what exactly you mean by "security". For example, do you wish to optimize for resistance against linear/differential cryptanalysis? Also, can you provide more detail on the smaller S-boxes, ideally their complete specification (in general the end result will depend on more than just the non-linearity). The easiest way to check is just to construct both round functions and test their properties. If you want a theoretical result (for any small Sbox), that's a lot more work (and then you should show some of your own effort, IMHO).

Comment: Still Wondering...

Answer (score 2):

About the security of your first variation, it is sort of answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34236/does-composing-multiple-substitution-ciphers-improve-security/34237#34237).

This is your 1st variation.
[image]

This is your 2nd variation (your $8 \times 8$ matrix idea is equivalent to apply a permutation).
[image]

In your first variation, the application of the matrix is useless, one can consider the $S1$ (or $S2$) and the matrix as a single S-box. Hence you have no security gain.

In the second variation, you can see that even if you find the right differential on $S1$, it became harder to exploit because you apply a permutation before the following $S2$ (and subsequently the application of the matrix which is equivalent to another S-box).

**Remark:** Because in the second scheme you use a permutation, they cannot really be compared (apple vs oranges...)

With this in mind, I will let you decide which of these two variations is the most secure...

**Given that you ask such a question** (meaning you are not familiar enough to find a weakness),
**I HIGHLY RECOMMEND YOU TO NOT USE SUCH A BLOCK CIPHER** in production environment **and stick to the standards !**

Comment: If I understand the (unclear) question correctly, your link to the related answer is unrelated: I think what the OP describes is only the round function, not the full Feistel cipher. Although the composition of several substitutions indeed remains a substitution, its various security properties for use as a round function will in general change drastically . In this regard it also makes perfect sense to compare both schemes, if only the OP gave us a more specific definition of "security" (e.g. he seems to be mainly interested in resistance against differential and linear cryptanalysis?)...

Comment: Using 2 S-box one after the other is why I think the answer linked is related while I do agree it does not fully answer the question. But at least it provides a nice explanation for the security about the first variation.

Comment: But when two S-boxes are applied after each other, the security properties can be completely different. Obviously the result is another S-box, but what matters is what the properties of this S-box are.

Comment: True but given the security margin he gave for his 8 bit S-box, I hardly think he could have something better.

Comment: @Biv Thanks alot for making a clear diagram for the variation-2. But may i ask why you are applying Mcamellia 8 times to all 8 bytes separately treating 8 bits as input? (or i understood it wrong way, and Mcamellia is being applied to 8 bytes just like in camellia)
From the Diagram you made, it make clear the Variation 2 will have better diffusion, changing one bit in input of sbox1, will cause change of atleast 4 different inputs to sbox2. which after passing from Mcamellia will propogate more change as compared to variation-1

Comment: The P-function matrix is applied on an entire 64-bit value in camellia, it is not a binary matrix, but rather an 8x8 matrix with only values of 1 and 0, which is why op called it binary

Comment: I didn't know that part about the Matrix, I thought it was applied on slot of 8 bits.  Well then it is just a big permutation of bytes right @RichieFrame ? And therefore it does not add security if you were to compare the two scheme between each other.

Comment: @Biv i have updated the question using your images (a bit modified)

Comment: @RichieFrame thanks for clearing the usage of matrix. any suggestion about both the variations? and any comments on my following understanding

"Variation 2 will have better diffusion, changing one bit in input of sbox1, will cause change of atleast 4 different inputs to sbox2. which after passing from Mcamellia will propogate more change as compared to variation-1"

Comment: @Biv Your opinion about both variations after the clarity on P-Box. and any suggestions about 
[THIS Question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35207/two-fish-mds-and-pht)